# Azure SDK for Node - Get 400 "Invalid URL" on every call

Tags: node.js, azure

Every attempt I make to connect to my Azure blob storage from the simple Node app below results in a 400 Invalid URL error.  I've verified storage key  ('mykey' below) and the storage account ('myaccount' below) is copied straight from the management portal, and the storage account is correct.  Is there anything obviously wrong?

```
var http = require('http');
var azure = require('azure');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;

var blobService = azure.createBlobService( 'myAccount', 'myKey');
var containerName = 'photos';

http.createServer(function serverCreated(req, res) {
    blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(containerName, null, 
                                           containerCreatedOrExists);

    function containerCreatedOrExists(error)
    {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

        if(error === null){
            res.write('Using container ' + containerName + '\r\n');     

            blobService.listBlobs(containerName, null, blobsListed);
        } else {
            res.end('Could not use container: ' + error.Code);
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    function blobsListed(error, blobList)
    {
        if(error === null){
            res.write('Successfully listed blobs in ' + containerName + 
                      ':\r\n');
            for(var index in blobList){
                res.write(blobList[index].name + ' ');
            }
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.end('Could not list blobs: ' + error.Code);
        }
    }
}).listen(port);
```

Comment: Do you have your node rewrite rule setup?

Comment: My node rewrite rule?  I may not understand -- I'm running node 6.12 on Mac OSX, not running in iisnode nor hosted in Azure.  I'm just going at Azure storage.

Comment: This is the error coming back:  `{ head: { TITLE: 'Bad Request', META: { '@': [Object] } },
  body: 
   { h2: 'Bad Request - Invalid URL',
     hr: { p: 'HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.' } } }`

Comment: Gotcha.  I assumed you were using iisnode. :p

Comment: Following up to note the resolution to this. For some reason I was creating bad headers with an `\r\n` in them.  I cleaned that up and had no trouble listing or sending blobs.  Debugging Azure SDK for Node code is helped along by a call to:  `blobService.logger = new azure.Logger(azure.Logger.LogLevels.DEBUG);` which gave me a clear look at the headers in the request object.

Answer (score 1):

Following up to note the resolution to this. For some reason I was creating bad headers with an `\r\n` in them.  I cleaned that up and had no trouble listing or sending blobs.

Debugging Azure SDK for Node code is helped along by a call to:

`blobService.logger = new azure.Logger(azure.Logger.LogLevels.DEBUG);`

which gave me a clear look at the headers in the request object.

Answer (score -2):

for management protal, you can try

```
var blobService = azure.createBlobService( 'yourAccount', 'yourKey','http://blob.core.windows.net');
```